# Get a list of values by key filter by condition that change for each key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a db like that:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": 1,
    "other_value": 7
  },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": 21,
    "other_value": 8
  },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": 3,
    "other_value": 10
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": 12,
    "other_value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": 13,
    "other_value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": 14,
    "other_value": 5
  },
  
]
```

I try to have a list of "value" by "key" where "other_value" is greater or equal to the "max other_value of the key" - 2.
For example, for the key: 1, the max "other_value" is 10. The array for the key: 1 is all "value" where
"other_value" is greater or equal to 8(10-2)

The expected result is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "array": [
      {
        "value": 21
      },
      {
        "value": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "array": [
      {
        "value": 13
      },
      {
        "value": 14
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I start with this but i'm block with the condition.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$key",
    "array": {
      "$push": {
          "$cond": [
              { /* condition */ },
              { "value": "$value" },
              "$$REMOVE"
            ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Someone have any idea ?

Comment: what if there is a third key or more keys? is this dynamic? and what is (10-2) can you elaborate more.

Comment: hello, yes it's dynamic. I must get array for all key. The (10-2) was an example. For the key 1, the max "other_value" is 10 and i want to push "value" where "other_value" is >= my max "other_value" - 2.